# camera expo base64 image send via http return 413 request entity too large

Tags: react-native, http, expo, expo-camera

I'm developing an app that uses the Expo Camera library for user account creation. The Expo Camera library automatically converts images to Base64 format internally. However, I'm facing challenges when attempting to send these Base64-encoded images to an API endpoint due to their large size. What are some strategies I can use to efficiently send these images to the API?
[base64 generate from expo camera :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1KhP.png)
[Log return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmVls.png)
I try to config quality on expo camera to 0, but dont work

Answer (score 0):

Do you can use the [PICA](https://github.com/nodeca/pica) to resize the image and compress. If you want to send by base64-encoded